# SQL outer join on two columns, returning null in one column if only the other matches

Tags: sql

I couldn't find exactly what I'm looking for in another thread.

Let's say I have these two tables:

left:

| x | left_y |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| a | 2 |
| b | 4 |
| b | 5 |

right:

| x | right_y |
| --- | --- |
| a | 2 |
| a | 3 |
| b | 5 |
| b | 6 |

I want to run a query close to this in intention:

```
SELECT *
FROM left FULL OUTER JOIN right
ON (left.x = right.x AND left.left_y = right.right_y)
  OR left.x = right.x
```

And get an output that has no nulls in `x`, but maybe has a null in `left_y` or `right_y`

| x | left_y | right_y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | null |
| a | 2 | 2 |
| a | null | 3 |
| b | 4 | null |
| b | 5 | 5 |
| b | null | 6 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `coalesce`:

```
select coalesce(l.x, r.x) as x,
left_y,
right_y
from l full outer join r
on l.x = r.x
and l.left_y = r.right_y
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=686bbe7c1975f846205b27803d7ea70b)